# AS3 Error Call to a possibly undefined method for Underline Function

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a problem with AS3.
I want to call Underline() method (movie clip class) in my code but there is error.

Here is the error:
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Underline.

Here is the code:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.data.*;
import flash.errors.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;



var underline:MovieClip = new Underline();
underline.x = tempText.x + tempText.width / 3;
underline.y = tempText.y + tempText.height / 2 + 5;
textContainer.addChild(underline);
```

This code works on AS2 but doesn't work on AS3
What is the solution?? Please help, this problem drive me crazy"

Comment: Here `Underline()` is not a method but you are instantiating a class.  
Aslo change to this `var underline:Underline = new Underline();`

Comment: If you are using the Flash IDE make sure the Movieclip properties are set to "export" in the library.

Answer (score 0):

As GoldRoger said, Underline here is a class, and must inherit the MovieClip class (extend). Also, when you are creating a new class, there must be a constructor function with the EXACT same name as the class.
For example:

```
public class Underline extends MovieClip
{
    public function Underline()
    {
        //constructor code, initialize here
    }
}
```